# How can I convert Vim keymap to lua?

Tags: neovim, lua, astronvim

Hi I am using AstroNvim.

Copilot help give me the following instruction about desired keybindings:

```
imap <silent><script><expr> <C-J> copilot#Accept("\<CR>")
let g:copilot_no_tab_map = v:true
```

In AstroNvim I have a file `mappings.lua`, and inside keybindings, but for copilot keybinding don't work.

```lua
return {
  n = {
    ["b"] = { "<Plug>Sneak_S", desc = "Sneak back" },
    ["<M-l>"] = { ":wa<CR>", desc = "close all" },
    ["<leader>;"] = { ":vsplit<CR>", desc = "split" },
    ["<S-l>"] = {
      function() require("astronvim.utils.buffer").nav(vim.v.count > 0 and vim.v.count or 1) end,
      desc = "Next buffer",
    },
    ["<S-h>"] = {
      function() require("astronvim.utils.buffer").nav(-(vim.v.count > 0 and vim.v.count or 1)) end,
      desc = "Previous buffer",
    },
  },
  i = {
    ["<C-t"] = { "<cmd>copilot#Accept('<CR>')", desc = "copilot expand", silent = true },
  },
}


-- imap <silent><script><expr> <C-J> copilot#Accept("\<CR>")
-- let g:copilot_no_tab_map = v:true
```

When I type something in code, I see copilot completions, but <kbd>Ctrl t</kbd> don't work.
Also `:verbose <C-t>` don't show anything, I don't have this key bonded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you miss:

- The closing `>` of `<C-t>`.
- The escaped backslash `\\`
- The `script` and `expr` options needs to be set to match the recommendation

I would do:

```lua
return {
  n = {
    ["b"] = { "<Plug>Sneak_S", desc = "Sneak back" },
    ["<M-l>"] = { ":wa<CR>", desc = "close all" },
    ["<leader>;"] = { ":vsplit<CR>", desc = "split" },
    ["<S-l>"] = {
      function() require("astronvim.utils.buffer").nav(vim.v.count > 0 and vim.v.count or 1) end,
      desc = "Next buffer",
    },
    ["<S-h>"] = {
      function() require("astronvim.utils.buffer").nav(-(vim.v.count > 0 and vim.v.count or 1)) end,
      desc = "Previous buffer",
    },
  },
  i = {
    ["<C-t>"] = { "copilot#Accept('\\<CR>')", desc = "copilot expand", silent = true, expr = true, script = true },
  },
}

-- imap <silent><script><expr> <C-J> copilot#Accept("\<CR>")
-- let g:copilot_no_tab_map = v:true
```

Comment: Thanky a lot, my friend, it's working. 
I'm so happy)))

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) You are welcome.